# firestore set operator do not add any document

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a promise chain to store user to firestore and authentication in an order. First time, i used add operator but i decided that i should store user according to their uid for that reason i changed my code and now nothing saved to firestore. What is wrong ?

```
 firebase
            .auth()
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then((data) => {
              firebase
                .firestore()
                .collection("Users")
                .doc(data.user.uid)
                .set({
                  name: name,
                  surname: surname,
                  email: email,
                  password: password,
                  nickname: nickname,
                  birthdate: birthdate,
                })
                .then(() => {
                  firebase
                    .auth()
                    .currentUser.sendEmailVerification()
                    .then(
                      firebase
                        .auth()
                        .signOut()
                        .then(
                          navigation.navigate("SignIn", {
                            message: "Please verify your email.",
                          })
                        )
                    );
                })
                .catch((e) => console.log(e));
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Note: The authentication works correctly.

Note2: There is no error on console.

Note3: I also noticed that if i changed the order like first store firestore and then store to authentication code works fine. Why in that order nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is that:

```
auth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data.user.uid);
          return usersRef.doc(data.user.uid).set({ abcxyz: "anything" });
        })
        .then(() => {
          auth.currentUser.sendEmailVerification();
        })
        .then(() => {
          auth.signOut().then(
            navigation.replace("SignIn", {
              message: "Please verify your email.",
            })
          );
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log(e));
    } else {
      console.log(1232);
    }
  };
```

And also the refs:

```
  const auth = firebase.auth();
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  const usersRef = db.collection("Users");
```

If i use `firebase.firestore()` and `firebase.auth()` in each case i guess they open a new function each time and this do not create a Promise. But if i create one single ref those then everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly [chaining the promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#chaining) returned by the asynchronous Firebase methods. In each `then()` block you need to return the Promise that is returned by the asynchronous Firebase methods, otherwise callbacks won't catch the result of a previous promise.

The following should do the trick (untested):

```
     firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((data) => {
          return firebase     // <== see the return
            .firestore()
            .collection("Users")
            .doc(data.user.uid)
            .set({
              name: name,
              surname: surname,
              email: email,
              password: password,
              nickname: nickname,
              birthdate: birthdate,
            });
         })
         .then(() => {
              return firebase   // <== see the return
                .auth()
                .currentUser.sendEmailVerification();
         })
         .then(() => {
              return firebase
                    .auth()
                    .signOut();
         })
         .then(() => {
           navigation.navigate("SignIn", {
               message: "Please verify your email.",
           });
         })
         .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

---

Also note that we avoid nesting the `then()` blocks, since promise chains are "best kept flat without nesting": more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#nesting).

Comment: it follows and jumps the all "then" but firestore still not saved the document.

Comment: No. Nothing catched.

Comment: Also the email verification send me an email and createUserWithEmailAndPassword works correctly but firestore do not saved the data

Comment: If i changed the order with first saved firestore and then create authentication user everything works fine but i need uid from authentication.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any security rule that prevents the doc creation? Also are 100% sure you look in the correct collection or project (I know it seems stupid but it happened to all of us at least once :-) )It is quite weird that it works in the reverse order (I guess you pass a dummy value for `data.user.uid` when doing so).

Comment: Yeah, i added some dummy values but nothing changed. Also i saw an issue on github. Is this the  problem? https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/3218. I use "expo": "~40.0.0", and firebase "firebase": "7.9.0", i changed my firebase version according to github but the problem sill exists.

Comment: I had never heard about this bug. It indeed seems that if you upgrade to a version > v7.16.1 it will be ok. I'm afraid I cannot help you anymore.... sorry.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any way for synchronizing my authentication and firestore Users collection with doing firestore process first.

Comment: "Do you know any way for synchronizing my authentication and firestore Users collection with doing firestore process first." => No, with the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` you can only get the uid after the asynchronous call has completed. You can assign uid to users if you create them through the CLI, see [auth:import](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#auth-commands), but AFAIK this is not possible with the Client SDKs.

Comment: @LeoS Note that you can assign a specific uid when creating a user through Admin SDKs. So you could write a Cloud Function that creates your users.